# Android ViewBinder values from cursor

Tags: android, listview, cursor, android-viewbinder

Hoping someone can help me here. I have a layout which contains listview, each item in the list view contains individual text fields to represent the days of the week --> SMTWTFS
What I am trying to do is change the colour of the text items if they are set within the database. This nearly works but I have noticed the first row in the list view changes the colour for all items when the are set in other list rows.

My text items are declared like this

```
        textSUN = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textSUN);
        textMON = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textMON);
        textTUE = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textTUE);
        textWED = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textWED);
        textTHU = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textTHU);
        textFRI = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textFRI);
        textSAT = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textSAT);
```

I then query my db and set the adapter

```
db = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());

            mCursor=db.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT rowid _id,* "+
                              "FROM table", null);

            adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),
                    R.layout.list_row, mCursor,
                    new String[] {DatabaseHandler.KEY_SUNDAY, DatabaseHandler.KEY_MONDAY,DatabaseHandler.KEY_TUESDAY,DatabaseHandler.KEY_WEDNESDAY, DatabaseHandler.KEY_THURSDAY, DatabaseHandler.KEY_FRIDAY,
                            DatabaseHandler.KEY_SATURDAY,},
                    new int[] {R.id.textSUN,R.id.textMON, R.id.textTUE, R.id.textWED, R.id.textTHU, R.id.textFRI, R.id.textSAT});
```

Finally I try to set the color in the view binder if the value returned is 1 from the db

```
adapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
                @Override
            public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int 
                    columnIndex) { 

                 final int sun_column = cursor.getColumnIndex("sun");
                 final int mon_column = cursor.getColumnIndex("mon");
                 final int tue_column = cursor.getColumnIndex("tue");
                 final int wed_column = cursor.getColumnIndex("wed");
                 final int thu_column = cursor.getColumnIndex("thu");
                 final int fri_column = cursor.getColumnIndex("fri");
                 final int sat_column = cursor.getColumnIndex("sat");

                 }

                 if (columnIndex == sun_column) {

                     int sun = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("sun"));
                     if(sun == 1){
                         ((TextView) view).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF")); 
                     }
                 return true; 

                 }

                 if (columnIndex == mon_column) {

                     int mon = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("mon"));
                     if(mon == 1){
                         ((TextView) view).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF")); 
                     }
                 return true; 

                 }

                 if (columnIndex == tue_column) {

                     int tue = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("tue"));
                     if(tue == 1){
                         ((TextView) view).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF")); 
                     }
                 return true; 

                 }

                 if (columnIndex == wed_column) {

                     int wed = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("wed"));
                     if(wed == 1){
                         ((TextView) view).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF")); 
                     }
                 return true; 

                 }

                 if (columnIndex == thu_column) {

                     int thu = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("thu"));
                     if(thu == 1){
                         ((TextView) view).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF")); 
                     }
                 return true; 

                 }

                 if (columnIndex == fri_column) {

                     int fri = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("fri"));
                     if(fri == 1){
                         ((TextView) view).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF")); 
                     }
                 return true; 

                 }

                 if (columnIndex == sat_column) {

                     int sat = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("sat"));
                     if(sat == 1){
                         ((TextView) view).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF")); 
                     }
                 return true; 

                 }
                 return false;
                 } 
            }); 

        lv = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listView);

        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Perhaps I am going about this all wrong ?? It nearly works though.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You still need to handle the cases where mon, tue, etc. == 0. Adding the following to each if statement should fix it:

```
else {
((TextView) view).setTextColor(//color that you want if day == 0);
}
```

Also, you may want to consider changing your whole setViewValue to use a switch statement, it should make the cod more readable.